# Back Face Culling for Line Loop

Tags: c++, opengl, culling

I am using z-buffer to render my 3D triangular mesh. However, when I rendered the model as a wireframe mesh, I also saw the triangle faces which should have been hidden by the front face. So, I used the back face culling as follows:

```
            glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            glCullFace(GL_BACK);
            drawWireFrame();
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

The drawWireFrame function is as follows:

```
void drawWireFrame()
{
    int i, j;
    glColor3d(1., 0., 0.);

    HE_edge *curr;

    for (int i = 0; i < he_f_count; i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        curr = m_HE_face[i].edge;
        glNormal3f(curr->prev->vert->vnx, curr->prev->vert->vny, curr->prev->vert->vnz);
        glVertex3f(curr->prev->vert->x, curr->prev->vert->y, curr->prev->vert->z);
        glNormal3f(curr->vert->vnx, curr->vert->vny, curr->vert->vnz);
        glVertex3f(curr->vert->x, curr->vert->y, curr->vert->z);
        glNormal3f(curr->next->vert->vnx, curr->next->vert->vny, curr->next->vert->vnz);
        glVertex3f(curr->next->vert->x, curr->next->vert->y, curr->next->vert->z);
        glEnd();
    }

}
```

However, I am still getting the same result I got before adding back face culling. Could you please help me identify what am I missing here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines don't have a front and a back face - lines don't have faces at all. Backface culling only works on primitive types which define faces, namely triangles (and traingle-bases primitives like strips and fans), and, for deprecated GL, also quad-based primtives and polygons.

If you want wireframe drawings of such primitives, you can directly draw them as triangles (or the other types) and set `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` to get wireframe visualization. In that case, backface culling will have the desired effect. Also note that setting `glPolygonMode` is enough, so you don't need different drawing methods for wireframe and solid renderings.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such a quick response! glPolygonMode() totally solved my problem! Although, I still had to enable back face culling explicitly for culling to work. I learnt something new. Thanks again :)

Comment: Well, you of course have to enable `GL_CULL_FACE` for face culling to work... :)

Comment: @wateva: btw, you could mark the answer as "accepted". That is how this site is [supposed to work](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)...