# Back face culling with GL_LINE_LOOP

Tags: c++, opengl

I know there's a similar question with a quasi exact title : [Back Face Culling for Line Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710612/back-face-culling-for-line-loop)

Actually I want to draw a wireframe containing triangles and quads and consequently, I really have to cull elements drawn as GL_LINE_LOOP.

In the past (when I had only triangles in my wireframe) I used the `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` solution. This way it works but now my quads are crossed by one of their diagonal.

Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: The linked question already explains it: There is no way to have backface culling for lines. The only thing you could do is implement it in some shader yourself: https://community.khronos.org/t/backface-culling-gl-lines/68993/7

Comment: So shaders are a solution. I'm not good with shaders. I currently use the simplest fragment and vertex shaders possible. Can you give me some explanations about how to use shaders to do this job ?

Comment: Basically, you'll have to add the normal of the corresponding face to each line/vertex. In the vertex shader, you calculate the angle between view-vector and normal and discard vertices where the angle is > 90°.

Comment: Yes, I read your link. Thank you very much. I'm diving into shaders and I'll tell you.

Comment: but do not forget to render all shared edges twice (each with different normal)